# Pushing Object Into Nested Reducer Array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, action, reducers

**QUESTION:** What's the best way to push a new payload object, to a nested redux reducers state?

I would like to push a new item location to the current lists array within the reducers function, using the current state index values.

**MY CURRENT REDUX ACTION:**

```js
export const addLocation = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.post("/inventory/lists/addlocation", locationData).then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: ADD_POSTED_LOCATION,
          payload: {location: "test", count: 0, _id: "6a5e4f6ae51g6ea5r1ga6e1rf"},
        });
    });
  };
};
```

**MY CURRENT REDUCER:**

```js
const initialState = {
  lists: [],
  currentIndex: {
    listIndex: null,
    itemIndex: null,
    locationIndex: null
  },
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_POSTED_LOCATION:
      const listIndex = state.currentIndex.listIndex;
      const itemIndex = state.currentIndex.listIndex;
      return {
        ...state,
        lists: state.lists[listIndex ].items[itemIndex].locations.push(action.payload)
      };
```

**My current result is simple**:

```js
lists: [a number, excluding the list objects and values]
```

**DESIRED RESULT:**

```js
Lists: [

    {
      _id: "L1",
      items: [{
          number: "n1",
          locations: [{
            location: "L1"
          }, {
            location: "L2"
          }]
        },
        {
          number: "n2",
          locations: [{
              location: "L1"
            }, {
              location: "L2"
            },
            {
              location: "L3"
            },
            {
              location: "L4"
            }, {
              location: "L5"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]

    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always shallow copy any part of state you are updating, including nested arrays and objects.

```
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_POSTED_LOCATION:
      const listIndex = state.currentIndex.listIndex;
      const itemIndex = state.currentIndex.listIndex;
      return {
        ...state,
        lists: state.lists.map((list, lIndex) =>
          lIndex === listIndex
            ? {
                ...list,
                items: list.items.map((item, iIndex) =>
                  iIndex === itemIndex
                    ? {
                        ...item,
                        locaitons: [...item.locations, action.payload]
                      }
                    : item
                )
              }
            : list
        )
      };
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Drew, I did some more testing with this. The code only adds the object to the first item of the first list. The issue is that I have multiple lists, with multiple items per list, with multiple locations per item.

Comment: @pc.dependency Do you have a *working* example of this I could also test? Maybe in a *running* codesandbox? I could see this happening if both `state.currentIndex.listIndex` and `state.currentIndex.listIndex` are `0`.

Comment: my apologies, the issue was just grammar, thanks! I will upvote when i get to lvl 15!

Comment: @pc.dependency Great! And no worries, I wasn't able to *actually* test that code so TBH it was entirely possible there *was* an issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed a few simple errors, and grammar. This is the Solution, Thanks Drew!

I learned that you must make **shallow copies** of your nested object structure using the spread operator (...). Also, utilizing the optional **.map() index** parameter allows you to use the mapped array's index values to compare with other index variables. Very Nice!

```js
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_POSTED_LOCATION:
      return {
        ...state,
        lists: state.lists.map((list, lIndex) =>
          lIndex === state.currentIndex.listIndex ?
          {
            ...list,
            items: list.items.map((item, iIndex) =>
              iIndex === state.currentIndex.itemIndex ?
              {
                ...item,
                locations: [...item.locations, action.payload]
              } :
              item
            )
          } :
          list
        )
      };
  }
}
```